# i can't query over populated children attributes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to query over populated children attributes using mongoose but it straight up doesn't work and will return empty arrays all the time.

even hardcoding right and existing information as values for the query would return empty arrays.

my schema is a business schema with a 1 to 1 relationship with user schema via the attribute createdBy. the user schema has an attribute name which I am trying to query on.

so if I make a query like this :

```
business.find({'createdBy.name': {$regex:"steve"}}).populate('createdBy')
```

the above will never return any documents. although, without the find condition, everything works fine.

Can I search by the name inside a populated child or not? all tutorials say this should work fine but it just doesn't.

EDIT : an example of what the record looks like :

```
{
            "_id": "5fddedd00e8a7e069085964f",
            "status": 6,
            "addInfo": "",
            "descProduit": "",
            "createdBy": {
              "_id": "5f99b1bea9ba194dec3bd6aa",
              "status": 1,
              "fcmtokens": [
                
              ],
              "emailVerified": 1,
              "phoneVerified": 0,
              "userType": "User",
              "name": "steve buschemi",
              "firstName": "steve",
              "lastName": "buschemi",
              "tel": "",
              "email": "steve@buschemi.com",
              "register_token": "747f1e1e8fa1ecd2f1797bb402563198",
              "createdAt": "2020-10-28T18:00:30.814Z",
              "updatedAt": "2020-12-18T13:52:07.430Z",
              "__v": 19,
              "business": "5f99b1e101bfff39a8259457",
              "credit": 635,
            },
            "createdAt": "2020-12-19T12:10:57.703Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-12-19T12:11:16.538Z",
            "__v": 0,
            "nid": "187"
          }
```

Comment: Can you add at least one record from `business` collection that meets your condition?

Comment: @Anatoly i don't see why we need that but belive me I am sure I have been trying to fix this for some time now

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use `business.find().populate({path:'createdBy', match: {name: {$regex:"steve"}}})` ?

Comment: I mean you to show in your post a content of one record that should satisfy your condition in `find`? I tried similar request and it worked.

Comment: I have a record `{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f229fee6d04771448e02611"
    },
    "title": "Book3",
    "author": {
        "name": "Author6",
        "age": 21
    },
    "__v": 0
}` and I tried `const result = await Book.find({'author.name': {$regex:"Author"}}).populate('author').exec()`

Comment: @Anatoly, yes that would be possible if your schema had an object as `author` but mine has a reference with an ObjectId. I still can't make it work really. I will try to add match inside the populate config and see if it works. although semantically that is not what I want

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no way to filter parent documents by conditions on child documents:

From the [official documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions):

> In general, there is no way to make populate() filter stories based on properties of the story's author. For example, the below query won't return any results, even though author is populated.

```
const story = await Story.
  findOne({ 'author.name': 'Ian Fleming' }).
  populate('author').
  exec();

story; // null
```

If you want to filter stories by their author's name, you should use [denormalization](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3).